# How can I reverse a transition?

Tags: html, css

I have made a transition to slowly change the background of my navigation elements on hover. But when i take the mouse of the element it instantly changes it to the one i had before. I would like this change to be slow like the initial transition.

Here is the code in HTML

```
<ul>

    <a href="#"><li><i class="home primary-nav-element"></i></li></a><!--
    --><a href="#"><li><i class="upload primary-nav-element"></i></li></a><!--
    --><a href="#"><li><i class="favs primary-nav-element"></i></li></a><!--
    --><a href="#"><li><i class="search primary-nav-element"></i></li></a>

</ul>
```

Here is the current CSS I have:

```
.primary-nav li:hover .home {
  background-position: 0 100%;
  -webkit-transition: background 400ms;
  -moz-transition: background 400ms;
  -o-transition: background 400ms;
  transition: background 400ms;
}
```

Comment: I think somethings go wrong on you html, too.  your html hierarchy must be ul->li->a, not ul->a->li

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the transition on the `.primary-nav li`, not the :hover psuedo element.

```
.primary-nav li {
    -webkit-transition: background 400ms;
    -moz-transition: background 400ms;
    -o-transition: background 400ms;
    transition: background 400ms;
}

.primary-nav li:hover .home {
    background-position: 0 100%;
}
```

Comment: You may also want to look into the ease-out control:  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-timing-function.asp